# For some reason my posts are not showing up on my front page

Tags: pages, homepage

For some reason my posts are not showing up on my front page after some small changes. Any suggestions? http://www.justgoodnewsonly.com/

Comment: As @Geoff already said, check back-end to be sure that those settings are correct. Some -small changes- can have huge impact as you found out, as long we do not know what changes these are it will almost be impossible to help you imho.When settings in back-end are correct then it may be better to ask help at Neodym, you paid for that theme so an option to ask their support to help you out.

Comment: my site [https://transcendentalmeditationmantras.co](https://transcendentalmeditationmantras.co) is showing only "front page" word written on its homepage and no post are showing up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming we're viewing a "Page" titled "Home"?

Be sure that Settings > Reading has "Front page displays" set to either "Your latest posts" or the correct page has been selected in the option "Posts page".